# How to handle GeoFirestore query's read operations?

Tags: geofirestore

I'm making an app where i can localize people around me. So i have a Firestore database that save all the user's location (users/{usersId}) and i make a query to find all people around me. My problem is that if i have 1000 people around me the query count 1000 read operation. Is there a solution to handle the number of read operation?

Here's how i make my geoquery:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
const geoFirestore = new GeoFirestore(db);
const collectionRef = geoFirestore.collection('users');
const geoQuery = collectionRef.near({
        center: user.coordinates,
        radius: user.distance,
});
geoQuery.get().then((value) => {
        value.docs.forEach( async (element) => {
              ....
        })
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem... If there are 1000 people around you shouldn't it make roughly 1000 reads?

Comment: Yes i think but i would like to know if there is solution to have less read operation. I mean i'm making a dating app and it's maybe not necessary to return 1000 users?

Comment: Because actually i read all the document around me is it possible to filter in the near query? Like collectionRef.where(....).where(...).near(....)

Comment: Yea, You can apply `where` filters. But only if it's for an equal to, you can't do greater than or less than.

Comment: where clause fail with this warning (Firestore: Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation`s execution.). I think it's because i have to create an index. I try to index the field g and d.gender for this query collectionRef.where("gender", "==", "male").near(...). Do you know which index i have to create?

Comment: Id have to see a picture of your indexes, cause what you said you did seems right.

Comment: I post an aswer with a screenshot

Comment: @MichaelSolati is my index right?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Thx for your answers,
Here is the index i created

Comment: index looks good, if it doesnt work, try reversing the order so the `gender` ascends first then the `g` field.

Comment: I tried to reverse but i have the same problem, it's strange